# Athena not able to read multi-line text in CSV fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

This athena table correctly reads the first line of the file.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_delete_email5`(
`col1` string, 
`col2` string, 
`col3` string, 
`col4` string,
`col5` string,
`col6` string,  
`col7` string,  
`col8` string,  
`col9` string,  
`col10` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'serialization.format' = ',',
'field.delim' = ',',
'LINES TERMINATED BY' = '\n',
'ESCAPED BY' = '\\',
'quoteChar'     = '\"'
) LOCATION 's3://testme162/email_backup/email5/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

This table is not imported correctly due to html code found in 5th column. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you provide us a simple sample of the input file, so that we can attempt to reproduce your situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your file contains a lot of multi-line text in the `textbody` field. This does not the CSV standard (or at least, it cannot be understood by the OpenCSVSerde).

As a test, I made a simple file:

```
"newsletterid","name","format","subject","textbody","htmlbody","createdate","active","archive","ownerid"
"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"
"one","two","three","four","five \" quote \" five2","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"
"one","two","three","four","five \
five2","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"
```

- Row 1 is the header
- Row 2 is normal
- Row 3 has a field with `\"` escaped quotes
- Row 4 has escaped newlines

I then ran the command from your question and pointed it to this data file.

Result:

- Rows 1-3 (including the header row) were returned
- Row 4 only worked until the `\` -- data after that was lost

**Bottom line:** Your file format is not compatible with CSV format.

You *might* be able to find some Serde that can handle it, but OpenCSVSerde doesn't seem to understand it because rows are normally split by newlines.

Comment: Is there any Serde that can handle this?

Comment: Yes, there might be another Serde that can handle it. We have only shown that `OpenCSVSerde` doesn't like the file format.

Comment: I pre-processed the file using sed -e "s/\r//g" and it is now working as expected.

Comment: Is there any Serde that can process a csv file that contain newlines or enter marks in quoted fields like " some \n text"? I am asking because it is not always possible to pre-process very large files.